# VisualBasic (.net) richtextbox?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

At first, my english is not that good, so do not hate, sorry about that. I am not English :'(

I have a question about richtextbox jump-in.
When I press tab, the cursor should  move a tab space (Jump in), like in notepad++ when programming css or html.

What I want to say:

```
<html>
   <body>
      Look this is spaced/jumped
   </body>
</html>


<html>
<body>
This is not
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a clue? I searched alot on Google, I don't even know how those brake's are named.

Yours sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `AcceptsTab` property to `true`. By default the tab button will move the focus to the next control but setting the `AcceptsTab` property to `true` will place a tab character into the `RichTextBox` when the tab button is pressed instead. You don't state if you are using Winforms or WPF but the relevant documentation is:

[WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, When I've got more reputation I will mark it as answer!

Comment: You're welcome @berm. Out of interest I thought you could accept answers at any rep (you just can't up-vote an answer)? It's no problem, I'm happy it's worked for you.

Comment: Ah I see, stupid from me haha, Do you maybe know how to get a horizontal scroll bar?  I've my multiline on false and tried some code's from the internet. I hope you have an trick.... I tried to change it in properties too... Hope you can help me!

Comment: @berm - it's possibly worth asking that as a separate question but I think you can probably set `Multiline = true` and `WordWrap = false` to get what you're after. You may also want to set `ScrollBars = ForcedHorizontal`